# Flutter getx is changing var state when changing language translation which it's not ment to do

Tags: flutter-getx

Please Look at the gif. [image: This is how changing translation is changing var]

The problem is the second number is changing value if I change the translation. Why changing translation is changing a variable value that is not related to the translation function. Although the app is named after riverpod, but only getx is used. riverpod is just in the name.
here is  [Github](https://github.com/rushdi1987/flutter-getx-test)
Full code check on GitHub Here is the code:
main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_riverpod/screens/screen1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MyApp());

}
```

screen1.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_riverpod/screens/screen2.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_riverpod/class/translation.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GetMaterialApp(
      translations: MyTranslations(),
      locale: const Locale('pt', 'BR'),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:  MyHomePage(title: 'test app'),
    );
  }
}
```

controller.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
var count = 0.obs;
```

screen2.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_riverpod/class/translation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_riverpod/class/controller.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key,   required this.title, }) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  // number variable  to store last state of the count variable from controller.dart
  final number = RxInt(count.value);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(title.tr),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => count--,
                tooltip: 'Decrement',
                child: const Icon(Icons.delete),

              ),

            Text(
              'text'.tr,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Change locale to Brasil'),
              onPressed: () {
                Get.updateLocale(Locale('pt', 'BR'));
              },
            ),

            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),

            Obx(
              () => Text(
                //count  value is in controller.dart file
                '$count',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ),
            Obx(
                  () => Text(
                '$number',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Change locale to English'),
              onPressed: () {
                Get.updateLocale(Locale('en', 'UK'));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          count++;
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
       // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

translation.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class MyTranslations extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
    'en': {
      'title': 'Hello World %s',
      'text' : 'This is EN Text',
    },
    'en_US': {
      'title': 'Hello World from US',
      'text' : 'This is ENUS Text',
    },
    'pt': {
      'title': 'Olá de Portugal',
      'text' : 'This is Portugal Text',
    },
    'pt_BR': {
      'title': 'Olá do Brasil',
      'text' : 'This is Brasil Text',
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: I think you have to learn more about GetX. Please take a deep look at official documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/get

Comment: very resourceful. If everyone could  find everything in documentation then stackoverflow would not exists.